# How to set dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled to false except for specific websites?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

How would I change the setting on a per-website basis? I really don't like when websites block me from copy-pasting my email or password into certain boxes (okay, I use autofill for the password nowadays so the security problem isn't a concern anymore), but I would still like google drive, for example, to hijack the copy-paste or context menu functionality as normal.

It would be nice to not have to open about:config and change the setting each time I use a website that I do, or don't, want to enable the ability for.

How can I set `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` and `dom.event.contextmenu.enabled` to false with exceptions?